# Fourier transform as a Gelfand transform

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

One question came to my mind while looking at the proof of Gelfand-Naimark theorem. Is Fourier transform a kind of Gelfand transform? Are there any other well-known transforms which are so?

Comment: any.. i need some real examples of gefland transform

Comment: A good example is $L^1(\Bbb R)$ where the product is convolution. We need to add an unity element, hence we work on $L^1\times\Bbb R$ with the operation $(f_1,r_1)+(f_2,r_2)=(f_1+f_2,r_1+r_2)$ and $(f_1,r_1)*(f_2,r_2)=(f_1*f_2+r_1f_2+r_2f_1,r_1r_2)$. We can give a characterization of the homomorphisms: there are $$h_t(f,r):=\int_{\Bbb R}e^{its}f(s)ds$$ and $h_{\infty}(f,r)=r$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the Fourier transform ***is*** the Gelfand transform for the commutative Banach algebras $(L_1(G),*)$ where $G$ is a locally compact commutative group. One can show that there is a bijection between the homomorphisms from $(L_1(G),*)$ into $\mathbb{C}$ and the elements of the Pontryagin dual $\hat{G}$, which is used to define the Fourier transform.

Some more details are in Kaniuth's book ["A Course in Commutative Banach Algebras"](http://books.google.com/books?id=Sp5uwaZsQLAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=kaniuth&ei=ifDhUJvoGqeUyQTR_YC4CQ&cd=1)   (section 2.7).

See also the wikipedia entry on [Pontryagin duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality#Pontryagin_duality_and_the_Fourier_transform).