# Are all function transforms special cases of Gelfand's transform?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, banach-algebras

Reading about Gelfand-Naimark theorem I've seen that the Fourier transform is a special case of Gelfand transform for the space $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with the convolution product.
In a related question on this site ([Fourier transform as a Gelfand transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268104/fourier-transform-as-a-gelfand-transform))
I see (if I well understand) that this is a case of Pontryagin duality. Now my question is: also other transforms, as Laplace transform, are cases of Gelfand transform? And, if yes, what is the suitable algebra of functions in which we can see such correspondence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$ is equipped with the convolution product
$$(f \star g)(t) = \int_0^tf(t − s)\cdot g(s) \,ds\qquad, \forall f, g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$$
then it becomes a Banach algebra. The Gelfand theory here corresponds to the Laplace
transform.

Comment: Thanks. You know if this result can be generalized to other transforms? As Hankel transform that use Bessel functions as a basis.  And to functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: I would recommend that you look at a good book on Functional Analysis to learn more about the Gelfand Transform.

Comment: Do you have a source on this?